# Vuelidate Typing

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuelidate

I am using Vuelidate "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.26" and "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.22" and Typescript.

In my components I am using the composition api, hence I initialize Vuelidate with useVuelidate(). However I am getting typescript errors in my tempalte.

```
    const model: Model = {...};
    const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, model);
```

then I would expect v$.value.$model to be of type Model, however it is of type Unknow and this gives me Problems in the remaining script. I looked into the type declarations of vuelidate and there T is defined as unknow by default but I couldnt find a way to overwrite this with my desired type.
So I am looking for help to define the type of Model and all the underlying props.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have to pass in the type as generic to the function:

```
const model: Model = {...};
const v$ = useVuelidate<Model>(rules, model);
```

Comment: This is what I tried first but useVuelidate expected two arguments and none is a simple interface